# Still pin capture on Linux. Is this possible?

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi, capture, snapshot

A. I have a general understanding question about the "still pin" or "snapshot" functionality on some web cameras: how does this work ? It must be one of the following possibilities:

1. The camera is on and video is streaming to the host. When the snap button is pressed, a signal is sent to the host's camera driver (/dev/input/event0 on linux), the driver extracts a frame from the stream, and sends it up in the stack.
2. The camera is on and video is streaming (or not) to the host. When the snap button is pressed, the on board firmware puts aside the current frame, and tells the host a new "still" is available.

B. I have 4 usb cameras attached on a R-Pi (single usb host). All cameras have a still pin. I don't care about the video, no need for streaming, I want to take 4 simultaneous photos. My idea is to trigger all 4 cams to capture a frame using the still pin. How can I capture those 4 images *without* streaming video (bandwidth issues) ?

Note: I have already experimented a lot and I am capable of capturing a frame from a video stream. My cameras are unknown brands but exposes "video capture" as device caps. When using AMCap on windows, the snap button triggers a snapshot.

Thanks for any help.